# Load Library Android

Tags: android, java

I work as cybersecurity consultant, and now I am on mission to reverse engineering of mobile app.

I always reverse it using Jadx and dex2jar... the problem that after reverse them I found some native methods with like

`system.libraryload("share_c++")`, `system.libraryload("android-network")`, and `system.securityloadlibrarry("mainJni")`

But I can't find the `.so` or library files. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Please add more information to your question.

Comment: Where are you looking for the native (?) library/libraries?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without the sample but it's possible that the native library is written to the filesystem at runtime, e.g. downloaded from somewhere or decrypted from some byte array embedded in the Java code.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to monitor all file-system activities e.g. using [inotify-tools](https://github.com/jrummyapps/inotify-android-tools).

Run it with root permissions, checking recursively for all read/write operations in the app directory. This should allow you to identify which file is created (in case the native library is decoded/decrypted or loaded from an online source) and what files are loaded.